# Does the lognormal distribution satisfy the Fokker-Planck equation for geometric brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematica

I've been trying to understand the Fokker-Planck equation and have hit a road block on what is basically the second simplest possible example, geometric Brownian motion.

Consider this Ito SDE for GBM, where $W$ is Brownian motion:
$$
dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t
$$
$$
X_0 = 1
$$

So the Fokker-Planck equation
$$
0 = \frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}} \left[ \alpha(x,t) p(x,t)  \right] - \frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial{x}^2} \left[ \frac{1}{2}\beta(x,t)^2 p(x,t) \right]
$$
should hold for $\alpha(x,t) = \mu x $ and $\beta(x,t)=\sigma x $, and $p(x,t)$ equal to the lognormal density function with parameters $\mu t$ and $\sigma \sqrt{t}$

I've attempted to verify this by plugging it all into Mathematica:

```
fp[a_,b_,p_] := D[p[x,t],t] + D[a[x,t]*p[x,t],x]-D[(1/2)*b[x,t]^2*p[x,t],{x,2}]
FullSimplify[
  fp[
    Function[{x,t},\[Mu]*x ],
    Function[{x,t},\[Sigma]*x],
    Function[{x,t},PDF[LogNormalDistribution[ \[Mu]*t, \[Sigma]*Sqrt[t]]][x]]
  ],
  {x > 0, \[Sigma]>0,t>0}
]
```

This is the output I get:
$$
\frac{
  e^{\frac {(-t \mu + Log[x])^2}{2 t \sigma^2} }(-t \mu + Log[x])
}{
  2 \sqrt{2 \pi} t^{3/2} x \sigma
}
$$

I was expecting to get zero.  Any ideas about where I could be going wrong here?